# Do I need to stop periodic GcmTaskServices?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement a `PeriodicTask` with the `GcmNetworkManager` API (existing since `Google Play Services 7.5`).

My task is scheduled as soon as my app starts and will check the content of a `Queue` of objects in order to send them as batches to my server.
If the queue is empty, the method `onRunTask()` will do pretty much nothing (it will check the queue and `return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS`).

---

I have put some logs in the implementation and noticed that the `PeriodicTask` keeps running forever, even after my app is in background or removed from memory.

This made me worry about my users' battery. Even though I won't perform any heavy task or HTTP request, the process is started periodically without real need.

At first, I thought `GcmNetworkManager` would be smart to exponentially back-off my `Task` until it stopped (or maybe I'm doing something wrong that prevents that), but, as my logs showed, that did not happen.

Afterwards, I have tried using `cancelTask()` and `cancelAll()` but those do not work if called from within the `Task`'s `onRunTask()` method itself. Even calling `stopSelf()` is not a good idea since `GcmNetworkManager` is the one responsible for the `Service` lifecycle so I do not want to get in the way.

The difficulty of actually finishing the task made me think if that is the right approach (maybe I should just let the `Task` live forever?).

---

How can I use `PeriodicTask` properly while not draining the user's battery?

Comment: Have you tried to send a broadcast that will force `GcmNetworkManager` instance to cancel all and prematurely return `SUCCESS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you really need periodic task execution? It sounds like you can register `OneoffTask` with [updateCurrent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask.Builder.html#setUpdateCurrent(boolean)) whenever you update your Queue. In case of upload failure, you can use [RESULT_RESCHEDULE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager.html#RESULT_RESCHEDULE) to retry later (and Google Play service will employ exponential back off strategy to decide when to retry).

I don't know your requirement, so you may really need `PeriodicTask`. If so, you don't have to worry too much about battery. The idea of `GcmNetworkManager` is that, you let Google Play service handle task execution, so it can execute multiple tasks together.

Phone will consume battery when it changes its state from inactive to active (see e.g., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3ry8PxcJJA) so as long as your job is executed in batch with other tasks and finishes your job immediately, you don't waste much power. You can configure [executionWindow](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask.Builder.html#setExecutionWindow(long,%20long)) to encourage batching.

Comment: Thank you. At the end of the day, I didn't really need a `PeriodicTask` (that would run indefinitely). I have altered my code to use a `OneoffTask` and scheduled one task each time my queue size reached the batch size limit.